# Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin using not local files

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

i have the following script with wich i want to do only one thing. Call a url and check if a http.status 200 comes back. I keep getting the "Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin." error though. I see several things on StackOverflow about this having to do with the local file system, however, i call http urls. Who knows why i get this error. I'm using Chrome. Thanks in advance for helping!

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function checkHet(invoer)
{
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
{// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else
{// code for IE6, IE5
xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
{
if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
{
document.write("Klopt als een bus!");
}
else
{
document.write("Klopt <b>niet</b> als een bus!");
}
}
xmlhttp.open("GET", invoer, true );
xmlhttp.send();  
}           
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form>
<input type="text" name="adres" value="http://www.">
<input type="button" value="Check" onClick="checkHet(form.adres.value)">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you are not allowed to use AJAX in other domains (and this includes the local file system) for security purposes. This is the [Same Origin Policy (SOP)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) in action.

But there are exceptions, especially if the target domain allows [Cross-origin Resource Sharing (CORS)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing)

Comment: Thanks for your respons Joseph, however, if i understand the wikipedia page correctly CORS should be supported by my browser (Chrome, latest version). How come i get the error anyway?

Comment: @RudyNijholt it requires the server to be configured to accept CORS.  Not all servers are configured to do so, and if ever they were, they are secured and configured to face the cruel world of 3rd party requests.

Comment: Thanks. Is there any other way to build a simple script to check if a website is up or down? (if i get a 200 http status, or anything else), other than just surfing there off course :)

Comment: @RudyNijholt a web server script can check for you. Request your server (via AJAX) do a wget or curl to the target server.

Comment: Nevermind, thanks for helping me, but for as far as i can see online, it's not possible without a serverside script, which i could do, but don't feel like it.

Answer (score 0):

- Local files should not be accessible by Javascript. Because if javascript can access local files, javascript may steal files on client machine.
- Usually, when a script tries to access local files, the browser will pop up a security dialog asking the user whether to allow the script to proceed.